# Establishing independence between seemingly complementary random sums

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I am struggling to work through the following problem.

Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n\geq 0}$ be i.i.d. random variables, $M$ a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$ that is independent of the random variables $X_{n}$, and $\{\varepsilon_{j}\}_{j\geq 1}$ another sequence of i.i.d. variables that are independent of the variables $X_{n}$ and $M$ and also satisfy

$$\mathbb{P}(\varepsilon_{j}=1)=p\,\,\mathbb{P}(\varepsilon_{j}=0)=1-p$$
 Define

$$X:=\sum_{k=1}^{M}\varepsilon_{k}X_{k}\text{   and   }Y:=\sum_{k=1}^{M}(1-\varepsilon_{k})X_{k}$$

Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

In calculating an expression for $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x,Y\leq y)$ I ineviatably needed to calculate

$$c_{\sigma}:=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}\varepsilon_{i}=\sigma(i)\right)=\left(\prod_{\sigma(i)=1}p\right)\left(\prod_{\sigma(i)=0}1-p\right)$$

where $\sigma\in\{0,1\}^{k}$ is any function $\sigma:\{1,2,\ldots,k\}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$. I have then calculated the following:

[image]

I have also computed expression for $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)$, but should I really be able to factor the monstrosity above? How would you show the independence of $X$ and $Y$?

EDIT: Dean has pointed out a subtle issue in this problem. If the indices of the random variables do not begin at $0$, then the problem doesn't quite make sense. I've edited the problem statement so that the indices start at $0$.

Comment: You haven't defined $Y$.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: I'd go for generating functions

Comment: Notice that for every realisation of $\epsilon_k$ for all $k$, the set of $X_i$'s included in the sum for $X$ are not included in the sum for $Y$ and vice versa. Thus for every given $M$ and any realisation of $\epsilon_k$, $k = 1,2, \dots M$, $X$ and $Y$ are sums of sets random variables that are independent of each other. Hence $X$ and $Y$ independent for every realisation of $\epsilon_k$ and $M$ and thus always independent.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Yes, intuitively I know that, but expressing that formally is my issue.

Comment: @RobertThingum I think you can use this intuitive approach directly. In the second step you have just used the conditioning over $M$. To that, you also add the conditioning of $\epsilon_k$ and additional sum over the space of $\epsilon_k$ and conclude the same way you would have done intuitively.

Comment: Ah ha, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my interpretation of the question, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. These random variables are functions of random variables:
$$\eqalign{X=X(M,\vec{X},\vec{\epsilon})\\Y=Y(M,\vec{X},\vec{\epsilon})}$$
While the variation from $\vec{X}$ is not shared between $X$ and $Y$, the variations from $M$ and $\vec{\epsilon}$ are shared.

As an example, suppose the probability distribution for $\vec{X}$ is non-zero only for $x>0$. If you consider outcomes $m>\lambda$, the corresponding outcomes $x$ and $y$ will both tend to exceed $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$.

Furthermore, the probability that both $X$ and $Y$ are zero is given by $P(M=0)=e^{-\lambda}$ which differs from the product of the probabilities $P(X=0)P(Y=0)$, and therefore the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ can be zero when $M$ is not.

Comment: For my example the outcomes $\vec{X}$ are only positive. In this case, if $m=1$, then one of $X$ and $Y$ is positive, the other being zero.

Comment: I'm still failing to understand. Would we not have that $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}=0\mid M=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}=0)\mathbb{P}(M=0)=0$?

Comment: Of course the term where $M=0$ isn't being considered here, which is the issue. I stated the problem a little differently than it is stated in the place I got it from. As i wrote it the variables $X_{n}$ begin their indexing at $1$, whereas the source of the problem just says "$\{X_{n}\}$ are i.i.d. random variables". Conceivably the index could start at $0$. That may be the issue.

Comment: I assumed your index starting at 1 was a typo, since $P(M=0)\neq 0$. In any case, I gave a couple of examples where it is clear that $P(X,Y)\neq P(X)P(Y)$. The variance from $M$ adds positive covariance: when $m$ is larger than expectation, $x$ and $y$ tend to be larger than their expectation.

Comment: I will have to think about your example a bit more, as I don't understand it currently.